# Flutter WebApp only finds some Image Assets when deployed to Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, image, web-applications, flame

My Flutter WebApp works correctly when running locally.  However, when deployed to firebase there are two sets of local image assets which the web app cannot find.  However, the web app finds all other locally stored image assets.  The problem assets are being accessed via Flame.  Other assets accessed via Flame are working fine.

`The browser console report:`
https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8poq.png

`Clip of Build Web Assets Directory:`
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqvST.png

`Clip from project directory:`
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKf60.png

`.Firebase Hosting File:`
https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8cdO.png

`Contents of .Firebase hosting file:`
https://i.stack.imgur.com/svw3n.png

`pubspec.yaml elements`
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CxTs.png

I have deleted the problem assets from the Build Wed directory, recompiled and they were successfully copied from the project directory to the Web directory.

- Flutter Clean had no impact.
- Reran full deployment from
  Firebase Init,
  flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit --release
  Firebase Deploy
- Using Firebase Tools version 11.28.0
- Problem occurs on Safari and Chrome browsers

Thank You.

UPDATE:
Kudos to Spydon for asking me if I can access the images via my browser.  I can access the one's that are working and I can't access the one's that aren't.   Now I have to figure out why certain assets aren't getting into my web build and firebase deployment.

UPDATE:
****What didn't work:****  Deleting all the Build/Web folder data, Flutter Clean, Firebase Init, flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit --release, Firebase Deploy.

What did work: Renaming the original image png files, copying them into the assets folder, flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit --release, Firebase Deploy.

"Fixed the problem but didn't learn the underlying problem". But I leave this artifact here for future prospectors and archeologists.

Sage